# Mvc-Ajax: Submit button not working, display returned result in existing html table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have the controller below with the Methods. One takes a parameter and the other does not.
I want to be able to do a search.

1. When I click on submit button. Nothing happens. My ajax call is not hit.
2. If question 1 is solved, I want to be able to type in my search criteria and have it
   return data in the existing table used in my index view.

Please assist. New to Ajax and mvc.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
                {
                    public ActionResult Index()
                    {

                        //List<Product> myProductList = GetAllProducts();
                        //return View(myProductList);

                        //List<Product> myProductList = GetAllProducts();
                        return View();
                    }

                    public ActionResult About()
                    {
                        return View();
                    }




                    public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
                    {            
                        string myConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectSir"].ConnectionString;
                        List<Product> prdResults = new List<Product>();
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnect);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from products",con);

                        using (con)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Product newProduct = new Product();
                                newProduct.Id =  Convert.ToInt16(reader["Id"]);
                                newProduct.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                                newProduct.Description = reader["description"].ToString();
                                newProduct.Price =  Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]);
                                newProduct.UnitsInStock = Convert.ToInt16(reader["UnitsInStock"]);
                                prdResults.Add(newProduct);
                            }

                        }

                        return prdResults;
                    }


                    [HttpPost]
                    public JsonResult GetAllProducts(string searchName)       
                    {
                        string myConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectSir"].ConnectionString;
                        List<Product> prdResults = new List<Product>();

                        string sqlcmd = @"select * from products where name = @name";
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnect);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandText = sqlcmd;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = searchName;
                        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                        using (con)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Product newProduct = new Product();
                                newProduct.Id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Id"]);
                                newProduct.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                                newProduct.Description = reader["description"].ToString();
                                newProduct.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]);
                                newProduct.UnitsInStock = Convert.ToInt16(reader["UnitsInStock"]);
                                prdResults.Add(newProduct);
                            }

                        }
                        //return prdResults;
                       return Json(prdResults);
                    }

                }

            *********************************
            Html

            @model IEnumerable<MvcAjax.Models.Product>

            <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <form>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="search" id="searchItem" />
                <input type="submit"  value="Retrieve" id="btnSearch"/>
            </div>

            <div>
            &nbsp;
            </div>


            <table id="items">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        UnitsInStock
                    </th>
                </tr>



            </table>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Home/GetAllProducts/',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { searchName: $('#searchItem').val() }
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        if (data && data.length) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var newTR = '<tr>';

                                //create your TR, such as
                                newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Name + '</td>';
                                newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Description + '</td>';
                                newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Price + '</td>';
                                newTR += '<td>' + data[i].UnitsInStock + '</td>';
                                //and so on...

                                newTR += '</tr>';

                                $('#items > tr:last').append(newTR);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            </script>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Send ajax with data and change content type to application/json; charset=utf-8", like this:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: '{searchName:'  + $('#searchItem').val() + '}'
        url: 'Home/GetAllProducts/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8"',
        type: 'Get',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
```

});

Comment: Thanks. This does not work. I was unable to get to the GetAllProducts. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on your first question. Your action is probably not being called because you're using a non-default route. Also, having actions with the same name and verb is not a good practice.

So, let's change your action signature to:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllProducts(string searchName)
```

`HttpPost` to change the verb, and `JsonResult` because we want to use your data with javascript, and that's the best approach.

Final change to your action, let's modify the `return` statement:

```
return Json(prdResults);
```

On your **view**, we must modify the ajax call:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetAllProducts/',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset-ut',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { searchName:  $('#searchItem').val()}
    });
});
```

As soon as we get this working, I'll move to the next question.

---

Now, the 2nd part. We'll add the lines using javascript.
First of all, let's give an `id` to your table. Let's call it `items`

```
<table id="items">
```

Let's add a handler to your ajax promise:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetAllProducts/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { searchName:  $('#searchItem').val()}
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data && data.length){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var newTR = '<tr>';

            //create your TR, such as
            newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Name + '</td>';
            //and so on...

            newTR += '</tr>';

            $('#items > tr:last').append(newTR);
        }
        }
    });
});
```

And that's it

---

For debugging puporses, let's replace the code within `done(data){...}` with this:

```
if (data && data.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var newTR = '<tr>';

        //create your TR, such as
        newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Name + '</td>';
        newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Description + '</td>';
        newTR += '<td>' + data[i].Price + '</td>';
        newTR += '<td>' + data[i].UnitsInStock + '</td>';
        //and so on...

        newTR += '</tr>';

        alert(newTR);

        $('#items > tr:last').append(newTR);
    }
}
else{
    alert('empty response. Please set a breakpoint at the action and make sure that something is returning');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment searchName is returning null in the GetAllProducts(string searchName) method.

Comment: @user2320476 Even if you have something on the `searchItem` text box? Have you placed a breakpoint at the action and verified that `searchName` is null?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did. I set a breakpoint on the method and searchName returns a null. I provided a value to search from the form

Comment: @user2320476 That's strange, could you add your updated code to the question?

Comment: @user2320476 Ok, I'm not sure about it, but could you remove that `contentType` line, please?

Comment: I just removed the content type and it works. Thanks a lot. How about the second part. I am unable to display the search result.

Comment: @user2320476 there you go. Let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks but I already have an existing table which my index method uses to load data on load of the page. Does that imply that I will not be using this anymore? Am I having two seperate tables now?

Comment: @user2320476 No, it's the same table. Just give it an `id`, like I said. We're just adding new rows (`tr`) to it.

Comment: Thanks. This does not work. All I get is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'done' "

Comment: @user2320476 I'm sure it works, I use it all the time. What version of  jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using  jquery-1.4.4.js

Comment: @user2320476 that's it, it should be 1.5 at least. Can you upgrade it? The current version (1.10) does not support IE8, so I'm still using 1.9.1.

Comment: @user2320476 Anything, so far?

Comment: Not yet sorry. I will quickly try. I had to rush for a meeting.

Comment: Still the same thing. No luck. I added my new code. Can you take a look please?

Comment: @user2320476 There is too much outdated code on your question. Please clear it and add only your current code. Have you updated the jquery reference to a version greater than 1.5? Have you added the `id` to the table?

Comment: Yes I added the version 10 and I cleared the code replacing it with what I have today.

Comment: @user2320476 I've added some code to debug, please try it and let me know the results.

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. I don't think its hitting the code

Comment: @user2320476 Are you getting any javascript error? Can you open the console (developers tool bar) to verify it?

Comment: @user2320476 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37129/discussion-between-andre-calil-and-user2320476

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data: { Name: mysearchName }
```

in your ajax call to

```
data: { searchName: mysearchName }
```

as your action method is accepting `searchName`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllProducts(string searchName)
{...
 }
```